# Google Earth Engine: Adding date and tile ID to entries of feature collection for later .csv exporting

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to extract pixel values for various sites from a Sentinel-2 dataset, across the entire time range available. I'm trying to add the date, and the mgrs_tile ID to each extracted entry, so I can export it as additional columns in the .CSV I export. I've attached a smaller version of the script below:

```
// Function to remove clouds + cloud shadow from an image, taken from collection page
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var tiles = [ '16RDV', '16RDU', '16REV', '16REU', '16RFV', '16RFU', '16RFT', '16RGV', 
              '16RGU', '16RGT', '17RKP', '17RKN', '17RLP', '17RLN', '17RLM', '17RLL', 
              '17RLK', '17RMP', '17RMN', '17RMM', '17RML', '17RMK', '17RMJ', '17RMH', 
              '17RNN', '17RNM', '17RNL', '17RNK', '17RNJ', '17RNH'];

// Create an image collection from surface reflectance dataset consisting of only images from days that had sampling occur somewhere
var sitesCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
              .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-02-14')//
              .map(function(image) {
                return ee.Feature(null, {'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
                })
              .filter(ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', tiles))
              .map(maskS2clouds); // Remove pixels deemed as cloud or cloud shadows;

// Visualization to confirm that just the desired images were extracted
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.3
};
Map.addLayer(sitesCollection, visParams);
print(sitesCollection);



//////////////////// BUILDING THE SITE LIST + FEATURE COLLECTION: ////////////////////
var siteCoords_features = [
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.3605,29.6432), {name: "Alachua - Alice - Lake"}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.1446,29.7842), {name: "Alachua - Alto - Lake"}),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.392,29.652), {name: "Alachua - Clear - Lake"})
];

// Creates a FeatureCollection from the selected list of coordinates
var pt_collection = ee.FeatureCollection(siteCoords_features);
Map.addLayer(pt_collection);
Map.centerObject(pt_collection, 10);



//////////////////// Pixel extractions of ALL coordinates for ALL days in featureCollection: ////////////////////
var outputData = pt_collection.map(function(feat){
  // only map over images that intersect with the selected feature.
  var filterCollect = sitesCollection.filterBounds(ee.Feature(feat).geometry());
  
  return filterCollect.map(function(img){
    var nameSplit = (ee.String(feat.get('name'))).split(' - '); // Split up the county + name + type designations
    //var dateSplit = (ee.String(img.get('Date'))).split('-'); // Split up the date into year, month, and day
    return ee.Feature(null,img.reduceRegion({
      geometry: feat.geometry(),
      scale: 30,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()})).set({ // set up additional data columns for spreadsheet display purposes
        "water type": nameSplit.get(2),
        county: nameSplit.get(0),
        name: nameSplit.get(1),
        lat: feat.geometry().coordinates().get(1),
        long: feat.geometry().coordinates().get(0),
        date: img.get('date')
        // year: dateSplit.get(0), // Why isn't this working??
        // month: dateSplit.get(1),
        // day: dateSplit.get(2),
        // gridID: ee.String(img.get('MGRS_TILE'))
      });
    });
}).flatten(); // Ensures we're only getting one spreadsheet table, and not collection of divided up tables

// Filter out data that didn't pass the pixel_qa filter, and thus had no pixel to extract from
var Filtered = outputData.filter(ee.Filter.gte("B1", -9999));



//////////////////// Export to .CSV file: ////////////////////
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:Filtered,
  folder: "Google EE results",
  selectors:(["water type", "county", "name", 
  //"gridID", 
  "lat", "long", 
  "date",
  //"year", "month", "day",
  "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B8A",
  "B9", "B11", "B12", "AOT", "WVP", "SCL",
  "TCI_R", "TCI_G", "TCI_B", "MSK_CLDPRB"]),
  });
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/653cc5568fac450dcddda4d7139f8b7b

Line 27-29 I thought would add the date field, but it seems to just blank out the dataset entirely. As for adding MGRS_Tile, I'm not even sure where I should be attempting that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 27-29 creates a new Feature per image containing nothing but a single property.  You probably want something like:

```
return image.set({'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})
```

Although there's little point in doing that, since you could just move that conversion from date to string into the `set()` at line 76.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid I'm still lost on getting the date exported, though. I tried replacing line 28 with yours, which did fix the CVS export, but the date column extracted was still coming out blank. I tried adding that line at the set()'s around line 76 as well, but that just yields errors no matter how i re-write it.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ae5f3887038024ca24c752881694b736

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Your maskS2clouds function was throwing away the date, you need a copyProperties in there.   Once that's there, it works fine: https://code.earthengine.google.com/44a20eccb6617ab460b4982dbfcd44eb